# How to use podman agent build cache with jenkins

Tags: kubernetes, jenkins, podman

I am using jenkins 2.387.2 for building images trough jenkins helm chart https://github.com/jenkinsci/helm-charts/tree/main/charts/jenkins .

I am using for this purpose a podman agent for building images in `values.yaml`

```bash
...
  podman:
    podName: podman
    customJenkinsLabels: podman
    image: podman-agent
    tag: 0.1
    alwaysPullImage: false #true
    volumeMounts:
    - mountPath: "/home/jenkins/agent"
      name: "workspace-volume"
      readOnly: false
    workingDir: "/home/jenkins/agent"
```

For each pipeline, jenkins is creating a new podman agent where pipelines are executing all build steps.

I would like to use build cache for each job to reduce build time. Right now, I am pulling previous image for cache and using `--cache-from` argument:

```bash
docker build -t ${repository}:${env.BUILD_NUMBER} -f ./Dockerfile --cache-from ${repository}:latest .
```

Is there a way to use cache build form previous agent into the current agent ?

Answer (score 0):

To fully utilize cache I would use two arguments. First is [--layers](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html#layers) and [--cache-to](https://docs.podman.io/en/latest/markdown/podman-build.1.html#cache-to). With those you will cache all layers locally and then push them to registry where you will store your cache. In that scenario job A will build some image and push cache layers to registry and job B will reuse this cache if some layers would be the same.